# Solving the functional equation $f(x)=\frac{2-x^2}{2} f(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function such that $$f(x)=\frac{2-x^2}{2} f(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2})$$ for every x in $[-1,1]$, $f(0)=1$, find $f(x)$.
Seeing the expression I think that a recurrence relation may be created by some suitable substitution but couldn’t proceed like that. I tried substitution $x\to\frac{x^2}{2-x^2} $ but then expression became worse. Or a trigonometric substitution like $x=\sqrt2$ $cos\theta$ but then LHS becomes unworkable. Please provide an approach to continue.

Comment: What is this from (if it is from anything)? Maybe the source has some guidance

Comment: There is [this other problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150057/prove-that-f-is-unique-and-express-fx-in-closed-form?noredirect=1) which is the same as yours but has another condition. It's actually from Putnam 2012 A3 [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h509869p2865742) so I think you are missing a condition.

Comment: Yes I got the error but can you please explain on what basis we selected the substitution $x=2t/(1+t^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hint that it 'can' be made into a recurrence relation,$$f(x)=\frac{2-x^2}{2} f\left(\frac{x^2}{2-x^2}\right)$$

Putting $x=1$, we get one initial condition $f(1)=0$.

Substituting trigonometric functions did not help me either so I tried to invert the expression inside $f$ be substituting $x=\frac{2y}{1+y^2}$.

$$f\left(\frac{2y}{1+y^2}\right)=\frac{1+y^4}{y^4+2y^2+1} f\left(\frac{2y^2}{1+y^4}\right)$$

Substituting $h(y)=f\left(\frac{2y}{1+y^2}\right)$, we can notice a pattern;

$$h(y)=\frac{1+y^4}{y^4+2y^2+1}h(y^2)$$

On rearranging,

$$h(y^2)=\frac{y^4+2y^2+1}{y^4+1}h(y)$$

Replace $y^2 \to x$,

$$h(x)=\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+1}h(\sqrt[2]x)$$

I think you can continue from here.

Note - As Gonçalo found, you should be getting $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: What was the basis of selection of the substitution (or what can be the hint?) $x=2t/(1+t^2)$?

Comment: 2t/1+t^2 resembles the double angle formula for tangent function. This was less of an intuition and more of trial error to resemble the expression in and out of f

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

By trial and error I found the following solution:
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}.
$$

Comment: If possible please provide a method through which it can be actually solved

Comment: Also how did you solve by trial and error, I mean what all functions did you assume before reaching to the correct answer and what was the way of approach?